# Deny access to admin from anywhere except localhost (using ngrok)

Tags: nginx

**nginx/1.12.2**

I'm developing a toy project. And it will be hosted at home.

I don't have a public IP. So, I'll use ngrok.
It is a service that forwards IPs like this:

```
http://bf3bf81c.ngrok.io -> localhost:80
```

Now if from anywhere in the world a user inputs http://bf3bf81c.ngrok.io in the address bar of their browser, http request will be directed to my computer and forwarded to port 80.

What I'd like to do is forbid access to admin from anywhere except my local machine.

Well, I failed. With ngrok all requests as if come from localhost. 
So, this will not work.

```
allow 127.0.0.1; 
deny all;
```

Well, I can't address directly to localhost:8000/admin. Because static files will not be used in this case.

The only way I have invented is:

1. Kill ngrok. So, nobody from outside can access the site.
2. Comment "deny" out.
3. Work in admin.

Uncomment deny directive, start ngrok.

Well, this is a bit clumsy.

Could you suggest me a more elegant solution?

**nginx.conf**

```
server {
    listen       80;

    location /admin/ {
        deny all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using below config

```
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {

    map $host $allow  {
        127.0.0.1 1;
        localhost 1;
        default 0;
    }

server {
   location / {
      ...
    }

   location /admin {
      if ($allow = "0") {
         return 404 "Page Not Found";
      }
      ...
   }


}
}
```

And it will not work on ngrok now

[image: NGROK]